# How to know drop position in Html5 drag and drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to replace JqueryUi droppable to html5.

And i need to know the exact postion of the draggable object on the moment of the drop.

I know i have the mouse clientX and clientY, but this changes depending on the place you started dragging.

Is there a way to have the position, or the object itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dragX;
   var dragY;

    $("body").bind("dragover", function (e) {
        dragX = e.pageX, dragY = e.pageY;
        console.log("x=" + dragX + " and y="+ dragY);
    });

 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to identify the targets you want to accept drops and wire up the `dragenter`, `dragover`, `dragleave` and `drop` events on it. Take a look at this if you haven't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop. I remember reading somewhere in there that on one of the events you have access to the x and y positions of the dragged element.

Here's some extra on `dragenter` and `dragover` differences I found during my own research:

- DragEnter is called when the mouse enters your control while dragging something.
- DragOver is called while the mouse is still in that rectangle and still dragging.

Rectangle is referring to the target element receiving the drop. Found those [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/be07bcde-6c99-4d68-824e-8ad93e820fe1).